# FetchAPI - piping response body to stream much slower than saving to blob and writing as a whole

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have a strange problem. I have recently switched from XHR to fetch in an attempt to implement streaming downloaded content directly into filesystem. I noticed a considerable slowdown between writing a response.blob to stream and piping response.body directly to it. Here is a first version, which is fast:

```
exports.httpDownloadImpl = url => headers => body => writableStream => left => right => {
  return async function () {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, { method: 'POST', headers, body });
      const blob = await response.blob();
      await writableStream.write(blob);
      await writableStream.close();
      return right({});
    }
    catch(err) {
      return left(err.message);
    }
  }
}
```

This completes in a few seconds or so for an 11MB file. The latter version takes up to 3 mins to complete:

```
exports.httpDownloadImpl = url => headers => body => writableStream => left => right => {
  return async function () {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, { method: 'POST', headers, body });
      await response.body.pipeTo(writableStream, { preventAbort: true, preventCancel: true, preventClose: true });
      await writableStream.close();
      return right({});
    }
    catch(err) {
      return left(err.message);
    }
  }
}
```

I suspect that the latter version may be slower, as we are interacting with a filesystem many times instead of keeping the response in RAM, but not *that* slower. Do you have any idea what can cause this?

Edit: I also noticed in devtools that sometimes it works just fine, pipes the file to completion, sometimes the request "hangs" after a second (i.e. payload size and response time don't go up) sometimes after a few seconds... It's quite non-deterministic actually. And when I close chrome in the meantime, the server logs show that the connection was closed by the client, so the connection is really open, just hangs for a few mins and then suddenly reports completion.

Comment: Is `writableStream` a [`WritableStreamDefaultWriter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WritableStreamDefaultWriter) rather than a `WriteableStream`? Because [`WriteableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WritableStream) has no `write` method. If so, **wow** that a confusing name for the variable.

Comment: Getting a `Blob` doesn't necessarily mean you've read the entire thing into memory, have you checked that? I wouldn't be surprised if `write(blob)` in your first version was in fact doing streaming. Still odd that the explicit version is so much slower, but I haven't played with streams enough yet. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the writableStream is a FileSystemWritableFileStream got from FileSystemFileHandle.createWritable()